# SQL query to output data from two tables that are not directly linked by PK/FK, but are linked through multiple other tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and DBMS' and so I am still learning best practices and exploring what is possible and not possible. I have designed a database in Postgres, which contains 6 tables: SATELLITE DATA which has a Foreign Key with CROP DATA which has a FK with FIELDS which has a FK with FARMS which has a foreign key with MET STATION and MET DATA which also has a foreign key with MET STATION. (I hope I've explained that ok..)

I was assuming that I could get an output table containing information from the 2 tables furthest from each other (SATELLITE DATA and MET DATA) because there was a link through all the other tables via PKs and FKs.. however I can't work out the SQL to do so. (I can envisage a very long bit of SQL to do it.. but if it is possible I would hope there is a more efficient way..)

My questions are: Is there SQL to do what I want above in an efficient manner with the same design of database I've done? Or should I redesign my database so that each table that needs to be linked, is linked directly rather than through multiple other tables?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I have tried to put in sample data, but the plain text tables I pasted in formatted funny on the preview and looked a mess. I think the description is enough for someone to answer - apologies for the lack of sample data though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from one t1
join six t6 ON exists (
        select * 
        from two t2
        join three t3 on t3.two_id = t2.two_id
        join four t4 on t4.three_id = t3.three_id
        join five t5 on t5.five_id = t4.five_id
        where t2.one_id = t1.one_id
        and t5.six_id = t6.six_id
        );
```

---

Now you  only need to replace the table/column-names by the actual names (that you didn't provide)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it better practice to have the MET DATA and the SATELLITE DATA tables linked directly by PK and FK as data is often called from the two tables? In theory it is extra storage requirements and so this is the reason I designed the database as I did, as I believe it is a more efficient way from a data storage perspective.

Comment: "efficient" has a different meaning in database modelling.  It is all about correctness & compactness & constraint minimalisation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

The query is not hard.  It looks something like this:

```
select . . . 
from met_station ms join
     farms f
     on ms.farm_id =f.farm_id join
     fields fi
     on f.field_id = fi.field_id join
     crops c
     on c.crop_id = f.crop_id join
     satellites s
     on s.satellite_id = c.satellite_id;
```

If I understand the data model correctly, these are all 1-n relationships and there is no issue handling the joins.  You just have to list them.  And, assuming the join keys are primary keys (in one table), performance should be fine.

You do have a challenge when some of the tables are n-m.  Handling multiple such relationships often involves aggregating before joining.